# Please reopen 'Why isn't my partition appearing?'

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [Why isn't my partition appearing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1401495/why-isnt-my-partition-appearing)

Ramhound kindheartedly solved my problem. Thus the post ought be reopened to let others read it.

Comment: The only way I would vote to reopen the question is to issue a vote to close as a duplicate.  I will be deleting my commentary by the way.

Comment: You could do with asking a complete question using words. Relying entirely on overly cluttered images actually limits the chances that people are going to spend time to work out what your problem actually is. [How to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). [How to format your question](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

welcome to Super User! The question is closed as Unclear what you're asking, as it's an incomplete question. See the Help Center, specifically under "How to Ask", to see what makes a good question.

The question closing does not mean it will be unnaccessible to others having that issue. If you can edit your question to make it easier to read and understand what you're looking for, it can possibly be reopened (and you can gain some rep!)